# TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined in jasmine unit test case

Tags: angular, jasmine

below in my TS file

```
   @ViewChild('creditName', { read: false, static: false }) public creditName: ElementRef<any>;
```

onChange() {`enter code here`
this.creditName.nativeElement.style.border = '1px solid red';
}

Below in my HTML
<input #creditName  />

Can any one guide me, how to write the test case for above...

I have tried below, but  nothing worked

1. spyOnProperty(div.nativeElement, 'style:border', 'get').and.returnValue('1px solid red');
2. component.creditName = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.for-testing'));

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing this in your test so that your component template renders:

```
fixture.detectChanges();
```

This also needs to be called after a variable is changed in the component if it affects the rendering of its template (e.g. in case of an ngIf that hides your input field).